# How to bind the height of one div to the dynamic height of another div using only Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Normally this wouldn't require Knockout, I would just call a function when I need to that sets `div1.height = div2.height`, but I'm doing an online course project and one of the requirements is that I need to use Knockout for all my logic. So I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use the style binding to bind your height to a js property. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html. There's no direct way to bind between two html elements so you'll need to use event bindings if you need to keep them in sync. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right you can define an observable variable in your model that gets set by the height of another `div`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/160/

```
 <div id="wantThisHeight">
  Div with a static height
</div>
<div data-bind="style: { height: DynamicHeight } ,text:DynamicHeight ">
  Div with a dynamic height
</div>
```

Model:

```
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.DynamicHeight = ko.observable(document.getElementById('wantThisHeight').clientHeight +"px");
}
var appVM = new AppViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(appVM);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, simple but just what I needed.